# Why does my Rails app work offline but not online?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'll be quite honest in that I'm not 100% sure what all I need to mention here, but here's the deal...

I have a basic Rails app set up on localhost, and it runs beautifully.

However, when I put it online, well...not so much. You know how you're supposed to set up your default route in routes.rb and delete/rename the index.html file, right? Well, I did that on both the local and remote versions. Local version: I get the exact view that I need as specified in routes.rb. The EXACT SAME THING on the server, though? I get a list of all my files in the "public" directory.

In other words, it appears that Rails is IGNORING routes.rb.

What should I be looking out for?

Comment: You should test your app in `production` mode on your local machine, i.e. `RAILS_ENV=production rails s`

Comment: Thanks, Harish; I tried forcing it into production mode on the local machine. Result: perfect. So...I dunno.

Answer (score 2):

If you're getting a list of files, it's not hitting Rails.  I don't know what web server is sitting in front of your rails app, but it's misconfigured.  It sounds to me like an Apache server that's just serving up a directory listing.

Comment: Well...I figure out that it's because I didn't have a dispatch.fcgi file. (I know, I know, you're supposed to use Passenger, but Passenger uses Ruby 1.8.7, which is incompatible with the latest Rails, so I'm using FastCGI.) Now my next step: figuring out why the dispatch.fcgi that my hosting provider told me to use won't work. (And they won't support it because the version of Ruby it requires isn't installed by default on their server...arrghhh...)

Answer (score 0):

Might be a problem with your git commits, did you delete the files before you did a push?

```
git add -u
git commit -m "Removed some files"
```

or:

```
git add .
git commit -am "add some files, removed others"
```